# Can a Schottky diode be used for RF signal switching using its low junction capacitance at high reverse bias?

Tags: rf, switching, schottky

For a project, I want to use an RF switch that can switch a 40 MHz RF signal (1-2 kW) with a peak-to-peak amplitude in the 1000-2000 V range. The switching frequency is in the 100kHz-200kHz range. The switching frequency and the RF signal's power range limit the switch choice. PIN diodes provide good isolation during switch-OFF state but at a lower frequency for high-voltage RF signals. Therefore, as an alternative, I am considering if I can use the lower junction capacitance of high-voltage Schottky diodes at high reverse bias. During the OFF-state the schottky diode will be subjected to high reverse bias so that the entire RF voltage swing will be between 0 V and the reverse bias level and theoretically, high reverse bias introduces low junction capacitance, therefore good isolation for the RF signal. Any comment/suggestion on this approach will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What diode would you even consider that has, not only such a high voltage rating, but several times higher, so that its C(V) curve can be effectively used in such a way? Let alone a diode in RF stripline package to be usable at all at such frequencies.

Comment: Simulation is your friend

Comment: You can get SiC Schottky diodes with a 3 kV rating, but the one I looked at had 78 pF of capacitance at 2200 V reverse bias, and it's in a TO-247 package.  Not too useful for RF switching, not to mention the cost.  Seems they are available in bare die, but that's another set of challenges.  
https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/PSDS/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/00004271A.PDF

Comment: @JohnD The [GAP3SLT33-214](https://genesicsemi.com/sic-schottky-mps/GAP3SLT33-214/GAP3SLT33-214.pdf) might be a better choice. It has just 5 pF at 2 kV reverse bias, which going by the graph in the datasheet seems to be pretty constant above around 1200 V. I'm not sure how much current is involved in Allison's application, though; this part's only rated for 300 mA forward current (1 A peak surge). It's also pricy, over $10 on digikey.

Comment: @Hearth Good find! I wasn't aware of those lower-current small-package SiC Schottkys.  As you said may or may not be useful for the OP, but worth a look.